# Manter o efeito do hover, quando o clicar no link (active)

Tags: css, html5, css-hover

Tenho um `<aside>` e dentro dele uma estrutura `ul>li` (menu) conforme código abaixo, gostaria que ao clicar no item e for redirecionado a pagina do mesmo o menu ficasse selecionado igual com o efeito do hover e que o sinal de + ficasse - ...

Tentei fazer usando css `:target` mas não deu muito certo pq eu teria que usar `#nome-page` e acabou não rolando .. entao queria saber via jquery qual melhor forma de fazer ... segue o codigo e a imagem ...

```css
@import "../main";

.aside
{
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 290px;
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 90px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 float: left;
 
 .aside-bg
 {
  background-color: #cac5b0;
  max-width: 275px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 0 10px 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
 }
 .aside-bg:last-child
 {
  padding: 15px;
 }
 .aside-bg:last-child ul li 
 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  &:hover
  {
   background-color: #fff;
  }
 }
 .aside-bg:last-child ul li a
 {
  font-family:'Optimist';
  @include font-size(22);
  color: #061f5c;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
 }
 .aside-bg:last-child ul span
 {
  padding: 10.5px;
  color: #fff;
 }
 .aside-bg ul 
 {

 }
 .aside-bg ul li
 {
  width: 105%;
  background-color: #061f5c;
  padding: 18.5px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  position: relative;
  &:hover
  {
   background-color: #ff5800;
  }
 }
 .aside-bg ul li:target
 {
  background-color: #ff5800;
 }
 .aside-bg ul li:last-child
 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
 }
 .aside-bg ul li a 
 {
  font-family:'Optimist';
  @include font-size(24);
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
 }
 .aside-bg ul li a span
 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 19px 25px;
  background-color: #ff5800;
 }
 .aside-bg h2
 {
  font-family:'Optimist';
  @include font-size(35);
  color: #0a2677;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
 }
 .aside-bg img
 {
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  width: 100%;
 }
}
```

```html
<aside class="aside col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5">
 <div class="aside-bg">
  <ul>
   <li class="aside-link1"><a href="formags">A FORMAG'S <span>+</span></a></li>
   <li class="aside-link1"><a href="historia">NOSSA HISTÓRIA <span>+</span></a></li>
   <li class="aside-link1"><a href="tecnologias">TECNOLOGIAS <span>+</span></a></li>
   <li class="aside-link1"><a href="sustentabilidade">SUSTENTABILIDADE <span>+</span></a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>

 <div class="aside-bg">
  <h2>Não é só impressão</h2>
  <img src="assets/img/icon-aside.png" alt="Icones">
  <ul>
   <li class="aside-link1"><a href="formags">solicite seu orçamento<span>+</span></a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</aside>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Nunca vi alguém fazer chave dentro de chave no CSS, pelo que sei, isso só funciona com media queries, (e sass ou less antes da compilação)... No caso deveria ser algo assim: `aside {...} aside.aside-bg {...}` e não `aside { .aside-bg{... } }`

Comment: pelas regras CSS aninhadas isso parece SASS ou LESS

Comment: @IvanFerrer  Desculpe talvez n tenha mencionado mas isso eh SASS

Comment: Foi o que imaginei, seria um SCSS

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade, essa questão pode ser resolvida simplesmente com CSS. Como você tem páginas específicas para cada link, em cada uma dessas páginas você pode colocar uma classe `active` no link correspondente à página. Então, no CSS, poderia fazer o seguinte:

```
.aside-link1 .active {
   /* Estilos que queira aplicar */
}
.aside-link1 .active span:after {
  content: "-";
}
.aside-link1 a span:after {
  content: "+";
}
```

Com isso, você poderia remover os "+" de cada span que você tem nas páginas atualmente.

**EDIT:**

Já que o `<aside>` é um componente que você chama nas páginas, você terá de adicionar a classe `active` pelo Javascript. Segue um trecho de código que faz isso:

```
var path = window.location.pathname;
if (path === "nome-da-pagina") {
  $('#idDoLink').addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: Mas o '<aside>' é compartilhado, ele é um componente que eu chamo em cada pagina, mesmo assim é possível?  Vou tentar aqui do jeito que você falou.

Comment: @Erick, então você terá que fazer como vc comentou na outra resposta... pegar a url com Javascript e adicionar essa classe `active` dinamicamente na página. Vou atualizar a resposta.

Comment: Legal entendi, tentei aqui mas surgiu uma dúvida, estou testando em um server local, no console.log(window.location.pathname)   me retorna  '/site/public/pagina' ....  poremmm se eu coloco esse path no 'path ==='  me retorna erros, agora se eu coloco no path so o nome da pagina  ai não retorna erro porem não da certo, mas vou tentando aqui acho que o caminho é esse mesmo, muito obrigado.

Comment: @Erick, mesmo que você compartilhe o `<aside>`, o javascript só executará na página que você estiver, ele não ficará fixo nas outras páginas. A resposta do Maurício parece atender à sua pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Não seria o caso de criar uma classe (exe. ativo) pro link que contendo o mesmo efeito do hover e na página de destino você verificar qual dos links deve receber a tal classe?

Comment: Então não sou muito bom de js, mas tava pensando em algo do tipo ...  quando entrar na pagina o js verifica a url pega o '/nome-page ' ai dentro do if ele ia verificar o nome da pagina e aplicar o efeito no li correspondente..  Mas queria uns exemplo ou uma dica se por ai mesmo que devo seguir.  Tenta aqui algo para adicionar uma class active mas n deu muito certo na vdd nao funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Coloca uma classe qualquer no body da sua página, um data-menu na li do seu menu e faz um JavaScript parecido com esse:

$(suaUlDoMenu).each(function(){
   var menu = $(this).data('menu');
   if($('body').is(menu)) {
       $(this).find(a:eq(0)).addClass('menu-ativo');
});

Por ex. Sua pagina tem uma classe no body chamada contato, e no data-menu da sua li vc coloca contato TB. Se bater ele pega o "a" referente a li que bateu e adiciona a classe menu-ativo.

Fiz isso aqui no trem, quem puder deixar a resposta formatadinha eu agradeço rs.